# How to setup delayed_jobs in Linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a remote Ubuntu Linux for testing a Ruby on Rails application. I deployed delayed_jobs gem in the application.

In my local machine, I used `rake jobs:work` to start the worker process, which will run all delayed jobs automatically.

I would like to start this worker process in Linux and then quit the SSH connection.

What's the best practice in setting up delayed_job in linux? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nohup rake jobs:work &` can fix the problem. Solved :)

Answer (score 1):

try to use `&` at the end of your command, in order to start `rake` as a background process:

```
rake jobs:work &
```

Now you can quit `SSH`

Comment: Thank so much Tudor. I used ps command to check if the rake command still exists. I found that it ended after the first delayed job finished. So the later jobs cannot be ran. Any solution?